# Which will perform faster for Iframes - Passing ArrayList or Individual DB query

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

I have a custom PHP website whose appearance is being changed. So, in the new HTML structure, designer has used 3 iframes and 1 of those iframes includes another nested iframe.

Content of elements in all of those iframes is generated dynamically via fetching data from MySQL database.

My question is what is best practice for fastest performance.

1. Pass id values(required to construct sql query) as parameters to Iframes & execute query independently on each iframe.
2. Execute the queries in main page, Fill arrays with query result in main page & pass arrays to Iframes.

-I cannot avoid using iframes.

-there are separate queries to be run for each component(data is in different tables), irrespective whether query is run in iframe or directly in main php page

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you are worried about overall efficiency, I would start by looking at the use of iframes at all.

If they are all pulling data from different files on the same domain, you're wasting a lot of time waiting for the network to go back and forth that many times to load your page.

If possible, use your PHP script to grab the relevant data directly from the file that currently is the target of the frame before you ever leave the server. Send all your data in one response.